# Как я могу изменить размер кнопок в левом меню в intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

Установила какую-то тему и теперь не могу вернуть обратно размер левого меню. (когда я переключаю на другую тему левое меню не меняется, только c темой Windows 10 Light)

[image: сейчасс]

Нужно:

[image: нужно]

Как я могу изменить это? Изменение шрифта appearance не помогает

Answer (score 2):

Используйте комбинацию `Ctrl+Shift+A`

Comment: А что дальше вводить?